# Sed with Character class [^[:space:]] not getting recognized

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu

I used following `sed` with character class `[^[:space:]]` as follows:

```
orig="(\`\`\`)([^[:space:]]*)"; 
new="\1{.\2 .numberLines startFrom=\"1\" .lineAnchors}"; 
sed -i -r -e "s|${orig}|${new}|g" ${InterimFilePath} ;
```

Input:

````
```bash
ls
```
````

Output:

````
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
ls
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
````

Expected Output:

````
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
ls
```
````

Any suggestions? Ialso tried the character class `[[:alnum:]]` but the result is same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output I get with GNU `sed` and with the native `sed` on OpenBSD is

````
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
ls
```{. .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
````

This is because your expression matches *zero* or more non-space characters after the three backticks.  Changing `[^[:space:]]*` into `[^[:space:]]+` would force the matching of *at least one* non-space character.

This gives the expected output of

````
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
ls
```
````

---

You may also use single quotes in your variable assignments.  This makes for neater looking strings without the need to escape special characters to protect them from the shell:

````
orig='(```)([^[:space:]]+)'
new='\1{.\2 .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}'
sed -i -E "s|$orig|$new|g" "$InterimFilePath"
````

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
orig="(\`\`\`)([[:alnum:]]+)";
new="\1{.\2 .numberLines startFrom=\"1\" .lineAnchors}"; 
sed -i -r -e "s|${orig}|${new}|g" ${InterimFilePath} ;
```

Output

````
```{.bash .numberLines startFrom="1" .lineAnchors}
ls
```
````

- use `+` instead of `*`, since `*` will match everthing.

Comment: `*` will not "match everything", but it allows for zero matches of the previous regular expression.